# PyPDF2 merges PDFs with wrong font or encoding

Tags: python, pdf, fonts, pypdf

I'm using PyPDF2 to reformat the pages in a pdf file. My goal is to take two pages from the source PDF file and output a new PDF file where those to pages have been scaled down to fit together on one landscape page. I'm using the following code:

```
import PyPDF2

with open('test.pdf', 'rb') as infile:
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(infile)
    first = reader.getPage(0)
    second = reader.getPage(1)
    target_page = PyPDF2.pdf.PageObject.createBlankPage(width=841.89, height=595.276)
    scale = 595.276/841.89
    target_page.mergeScaledTranslatedPage(first, scale, 0, 0)
    target_page.mergeScaledTranslatedPage(second, scale, 841.89/2, 0)
    writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    writer.addMetadata(reader.documentInfo)
    writer.addPage(target_page)
with open('wrong.pdf', 'wb') as outfile:
    writer.write(outfile)
```

The output almost matches my expectations, but seems to use a different font with bad kerning and some special characters displayed incorrectly. I'm not familiar with the internals of the PDF format, so I don't know what causes this.

How can I make the content be displayed exactly the same way as the source (apart from being scaled down)?